# Log rules for calculating joint entropy

Tags: logarithms, entropy

This question is probably not so hard for you.

Why is the entropy equal to:

$$
H(x,y)=2\log_2(5)-\frac{8}{25}\log_2(2)-\frac{6}{25}\log_2(3),
$$

for the following joint distribution?

$$
p(x,y) = 
\frac{1}{25}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
2&1&2&0&0\\
2&0&1&1&1\\
0&3&0&2&0\\
0&0&1&1&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My answer is:
$$
H(x,y)=\frac{11}{25}\log_2(\frac{1}{25})-\frac{8}{25}\log_2(\frac{2}{25})-\frac{6}{25}\log_2(\frac{3}{25}),
$$

and the only thing I could think of applying here is $\log(\frac{1}{x})=-\log(x)$ and $\log_2(2)=1$.
Which is useful for $-\log_2(\frac{1}{25})=\log_2(25)=\log_2(5^2)=2\log(5)$.

Hope someone can help. Its from this book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-79234-7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you need help with logarithms simplification? Because I think your calculations are almost (possible typo) ok:

> My answer is: $H(x,y)=\frac{11}{25}\log_2(\frac{1}{25})-\frac{8}{25}\log_2(\frac{2}{25})-\frac{6}{25}\log_2(\frac{3}{25}).$

I thing you miss minus sine $H(x,y)=-\frac{11}{25}\log_2\frac{1}{25}-\frac{8}{25}\log_2\frac{2}{25}-\frac{6}{25}\log_2\frac{3}{25}.$ Sincethe joint Shannon’s entropy is given by $$H(X,Y)=-\sum_{x\in X}\sum_{y\in Y}p(x,y)\log p(x,y)$$
while I'm referring to notation from your book *Information Theory
and Network Coding, Raymond W. Yeung* p. 43. So let's simplify logarithms. But at first notice there are many equivalents ways to do this so you (and potential reader) do not have to stick with mine. Since $$-\frac{11}{25}\log_2\frac{1}{25} = \frac{11}{25}\log_2 25 = \frac{22}{25}\log_2 5  \\  -\frac{8}{25}\log_2\frac{2}{25}= -\frac{8}{25}\log_2 2 + \frac{8}{25}\log_2 25 = -\frac{8}{25} + \frac{16}{25}\log_2 5 \\ -\frac{6}{25}\log_2\frac{3}{25} = -\frac{6}{25}\log_2 3 +\frac{6}{25}\log_2 25=  -\frac{6}{25}\log_2 3 +\frac{12}{25}\log_2 5. $$ I'm using dwo facts $$\log \xi/\eta =\log \xi -\log \eta \qquad \& \qquad  \log \xi^{\eta}=\eta \log \xi. $$ At the end sum up everything $$\frac{22}{25}\log_2 5  -\frac{8}{25} + \frac{16}{25}\log_2 5 -\frac{6}{25}\log_2 3 +\frac{12}{25}\log_2 5 = 2 \log_2 5 -\frac{8}{25} -\frac{6}{25}\log_2 3  $$ what is the expected answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that all three terms would be equal, in my initial answer and the solutions manual. And stupidly forgot to split fractions inside the log as additions/subtractions, which then result again in three terms.